# PHP not sending mail, sendmail works

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, sendmail

This one is throwing me for a loop.

I know sendmail is configured correctly because:

```
sendmail -s "test" example@gmail.com
test
```

correctly sends mail, with the correct reverse domain, etc.

However, this script:

```
<?php
$to='dest@domain.com';
$what='Mail Test';
$body="Can this body be read? on ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$header="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\nFrom:Blackhole<blackhole@domain.com>\r\n";
if(mail($to,$what,$body,$header)) $message="This just sent an email to $to .";
else $message="The email FAILED to send here to $to";
?>
<p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
```

Gives me the failure message. I'm using the default sendmail path in `php.ini`, and it was working this morning until I added a MASQUARADE to sendmail and added `local-host-names`. The whole configuration was then updated with `sendmailconfig`, so all the dependencies were updated. The following code was inserted on line 55 after the whole boatload of `dnl # {comment}` entries.

```
MASQUERADE_AS(domain.com)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(domain.com)
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `domain.com')dnl
```

The only error I get in configuration is that `Errors in generating sendmail.cf
m4:/etc/mail/sendmail.mc:108: Warning: end of file treated as newline`

However, reverting this did not cause mail to start working again.

Running on Ubuntu server on an Amazon AWS instance.

Comment: So what errors are you getting?

Comment: No error at all shows up in my php or apache error log, stunningly (nor in the wordpress `debug.log`). I even created new blank versions of several of them to make sure.

Comment: the mail server log is where you want to check

Comment: Aha! Thanks. Our mailserver is handled by Godaddy, so I was sending an email to one of those emails -- and it was returning "user uknown". It works if it's not a domain that this is mapped to. Is there a way to force sendmail to actually go through the whole SMTP process even if it's theoretically one of "these" users?